# Create a trigger to run scalar-valued function in it FOR INSERT

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers, sql-function

I created a trigger as below to check whether the UDF are available or not if are then DROP them and create new UDF, then at last Use them on a table named **TableToClean.**
But it's not working-

```
USE [DB2]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[cleanData]    Script Date: 7/22/2014 3:33:19 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[cleanData]
ON [dbo].[TableToClean] FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON
            IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[cleanStyleData]') IS NOT NULL
             DROP FUNCTION cleanStyleData
            GO

        CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[cleanStyleData] ( @StyleText VARCHAR(MAX) )
        RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
        AS BEGIN
            DECLARE @Start INT
            DECLARE @End INT
            DECLARE @Length INT
            SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<style>', @StyleText)
            SET @End = CHARINDEX('</style>', @StyleText, @Start)
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1
            WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @StyleText = STUFF(@StyleText, @Start, @Length, '')
                    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<style>', @StyleText)
                    SET @End = CHARINDEX('</style>', @StyleText, @Start)
                    SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1
                END
            RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@StyleText)), '$', ''), '£', ''), '€', ''), '&#8629;', '')
        END

        IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[cleanScriptData]') IS NOT NULL
         DROP FUNCTION cleanScriptData
        GO

        CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[cleanScriptData] ( @ScriptText VARCHAR(MAX) )
        RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
        AS BEGIN
            DECLARE @Start INT
            DECLARE @End INT
            DECLARE @Length INT
            SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<script>', @ScriptText)
            SET @End = CHARINDEX('</script>', @ScriptText, @Start)
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1
            WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @ScriptText = STUFF(@ScriptText, @Start, @Length, '')
                    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<script>', @ScriptText)
                    SET @End = CHARINDEX('</script>', @ScriptText, @Start)
                    SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1
                END
            RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@ScriptText)), '=', ''), '\', ''), '||', '')
        END

        UPDATE [DB2].[dbo].[TableToClean]
        SET [DA_ArticleDetails] = [dbo].[cleanStyleData] ([DA_ArticleDetails])

        UPDATE [DB2].[dbo].[TableToClean]
        SET [DA_ArticleDetails] = [dbo].[cleanScriptData] ([DA_ArticleDetails])

END
```

I tried to execute it but giving errors.

Comment: Why on earth do those functions have to be rebuilt by the trigger?

Comment: Also, I'm just about to insert `<script type="text/javascript>DoBadThings()</script     >` into that table - is that alright with you?

Comment: Hi,
Because our developers are constantly updating the function so new UDF should be used and old should get deleted or I'll use alter function.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, bro all the tags will also get deleted in other function which I haven't listed in the code. Could you plz help?

Comment: You have a performance timebomb on your hands with this approach. Scalar functions are notoriously slow. Calling from a trigger is even worse. Then you add to that the very bizarre concept of dropping functions and recreating them before calling them inside a trigger. If you have to do this sort of thing inside a trigger because other people are changing the code this is the wrong way to fix it. You are dealing with the symptom instead of the cause. Revoke their permissions to edit these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `Exec()` command.

Try this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[cleanData]
ON [dbo].[TableToClean] FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[cleanStyleData]') IS NOT NULL
        DROP FUNCTION cleanStyleData

    DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Command = '
        CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[cleanStyleData] ( @StyleText VARCHAR(MAX) )
        RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
        AS BEGIN
            DECLARE @Start INT
            DECLARE @End INT
            DECLARE @Length INT
            SET @Start = CHARINDEX(''<style>'', @StyleText)
            SET @End = CHARINDEX(''</style>'', @StyleText, @Start)
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1
            WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @StyleText = STUFF(@StyleText, @Start, @Length, '')
                    SET @Start = CHARINDEX(''<style>'', @StyleText)
                    SET @End = CHARINDEX(''</style>'', @StyleText, @Start)
                    SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1
                END
            RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@StyleText)), ''$'', ''''), ''£'', ''''), ''€'', ''''), ''&#8629;'', '''')
        END'
        EXEC(@Command)

        IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[cleanScriptData]') IS NOT NULL
           DROP FUNCTION cleanScriptData

        DECLARE @command = '
        CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[cleanScriptData] ( @ScriptText VARCHAR(MAX) )
        RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
        AS BEGIN
            DECLARE @Start INT
            DECLARE @End INT
            DECLARE @Length INT
            SET @Start = CHARINDEX(''<script>'', @ScriptText)
            SET @End = CHARINDEX(''</script>'', @ScriptText, @Start)
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1
            WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @ScriptText = STUFF(@ScriptText, @Start, @Length, '')
                    SET @Start = CHARINDEX(''<script>'', @ScriptText)
                    SET @End = CHARINDEX(''</script>'', @ScriptText, @Start)
                    SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1
                END
            RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@ScriptText)), ''='', ''''), ''\'', ''''), ''||'', '''')
        END'
        EXEC(@Command)

        SET @Command = '
        UPDATE [DB2].[dbo].[TableToClean]
        SET [DA_ArticleDetails] = [dbo].[cleanStyleData] ([DA_ArticleDetails])'
        EXEC(@Command)

        SET @Command = '
        UPDATE [DB2].[dbo].[TableToClean]
        SET [DA_ArticleDetails] = [dbo].[cleanScriptData] ([DA_ArticleDetails])'
        EXEC(@Command)
END
```